# How to update list value in dictionary in Python

Tags: python

Beginner here. I'm currently writing a program that will turn every word in a "movie reviews" text file into a key, storing a list value containing the review number and the number of times the word has been seen. For example:

```
4 I loved it

1 I hated it
```

... might look like this as a dictionary:

```
words['i']     = [5,2]

words['loved'] = [4,1]

words['it']    = [5,2]

words['hated'] = [1,1]
```

However, this is the output I've been getting:

```
{'i': [1, 2], 'loved': [4, 1], 'it': [1, 2], 'hated': [1, 1]}
```

I figured out the counter part, but I can't figure out how to update the review number. Here is my code so far:

```
def main():

    reviews = open("testing.txt", "r")
    data = reviews.read();
    reviews.close()

    # create new dictionary
    words = {}

    # iterate over every review in text file
    splitlines = data.split("\n")

    for line in splitlines:
        lower = line.lower()
        value = lower.split()
        rev = int(value[0])
        for word in value:
            if word.isalpha():
                count = 1
                if word not in words:
                    words[word] = [rev, count]
                else:
                    words[word] = [rev, count + 1]
```

How can I update the review number count?

Comment: One issue I see: You always initialize count to 1, then you either insert it or you add 1 then insert it, so it will only ever be 1 or 2. You need to take in the existing value before you try to increment it

Comment: Hello Gabi, I can't figure properly what you are trying to do: you need to count the occurrences of a word in a file? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bag-of-words_model

Comment: @MazziottiRaffaele Yes, exactly. I need to count the amount of occurrences of each unique word in the file.

Comment: what's the meaning of `words['loved'] = [4,1]` -- the word `loved` was seen 1 time in 4 different reviews??

Comment: @lenik 4 = the review number. In my test text file, the 4 in "4 I loved it" is the rating the reviewer gave it out of 5. 1 is the amount of times the word loved was seen in the entire text file.

Comment: ok, what about `words['it']    = [5,2]` then? `it` was seen twice in the same review number 5? what would happen if it was seen in a different reviews?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is pretty easy to do. Assuming each key has only 2 items in the value list:

```
if word not in words:
    words[word] = [rev, 1]
else:
    temp = words[word][1]
    words[word] = [rev, temp + 1]
```

Comment: I think the issue is in your `count=1` . I will modify my answer now

Comment: Still the same output :(

Comment: Okay, so if you are trying to update review number , you can do this:`words[word] = [words[word][0]+1, temp+1]`

Comment: Providing that I got your question right. It should be placed in the `else` clause

Answer (score 0):

When updating the count, you're using `count + 1`, but `count` will always be 1 here; you need to retrieve the existing count first, using something like: `count = words[word][1]`